# Javascript Reactjs button component not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple button component in react.

Here is the code:

```
//buttons.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {children, className, href, icon} = this.props;
    const props = {href, className, ref: 'button', disabled: this.props.disabled };
    const element = href ? 'a' : 'button';

    return React.createElement(
      element, props, icon ? <i className={this.props.icon} /> : null, children
    );
  }
}

//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Button from './components/buttons';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button className="btn-primary">click me</Button>
    <Button className="btn-success" icon="fa fa-phone">success </Button>
    <Button className="btn-success" disabled={true}>disabled </Button>
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//index.html 

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

        <div id='root'></div>

    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is that no button is showing at all.
The console is showing the following error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Why is/are the button(s) not showing?

Comment: you don't seem to be exporting `Button` in `buttons.js`. Is that an example typo or is that exactly what you have in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is in this line: `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`
You used a extra `/`, remove this it should work because same code is working properly on `jsfiddle`.

https://jsfiddle.net/5469dwwc/

Answer (score 0):

Fault was in relative path ..

```
//buttons.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {children, className, href, icon} = this.props;
    const props = {href, className, ref: 'button', disabled: this.props.disabled };
    const element = href ? 'a' : 'button';

    return React.createElement(
      element, props, icon ? <i className={this.props.icon} /> : null, children
    );
  }
}

//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Button from '../components/buttons';
//-----------------^^^^--------------here
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button className="btn-primary">click me</Button>
    <Button className="btn-success" icon="fa fa-phone">success </Button>
    <Button className="btn-success" disabled={true}>disabled </Button>
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//index.html 

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

        <div id='root'></div>

    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```